# Cast in query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to `cast` orderBy in query builder laravel

because my `price` is `varchar` type..

so when it's sorting...the result is far from I want...

my script like this

```
DB::table('test')->where(...)->orderBy('price')->get();
```

i already try something like this

```
$query = CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC;
DB::table('test')->where(...)->orderBy($query)->get();
```

how can I cast OrderBy query builder so I can sort `price` desc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try it with `orderByRaw()`:

```
$query = "CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC";
DB::table('test')->where(...)->orderByRaw($query)->get();
```

Comment: try `$query = "CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC";` with quotation marks.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Cheers.