# Laravel eloquent orderBy a number hundreds first and not last

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a small (i hope) problem and hope one of you might be able to help me :)

Got the following values in my database: 56, 63, 75, 80, 90, 100, 132

I got this code:

```
MotorSize::orderBy('framesize', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Then in blade:

```
@foreach($motor_sizes as $motor_size)
    {{ $motor_size->name }}
@endforeach
```

I would expect the output to be: 56, 63, 75, 80, 90, 100, 132

But the output is: 100, 132, 56, 63, 75, 80, 90

Why is that and how can it be fixed? I guess it's related to the starting integer of the value.

The Database table related to the value:

```
$table->string('framesize');
```

Maybe because it's not an integer? Any fix for that?

Comment: because the results are ordered alphabetically and not numerically. The field you are ordering with is of type `string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713490/cast-in-query-builder-laravel

Comment: Yes, orderByRaw("CAST(framesize as UNSIGNED) ASC") did the trick :)

Comment: @KennethPoulsen accept my answer if that was helpful.

Comment: Why store as string though? You are making the query to do additional processing. Actual answer is to just change the datatype of DB column.

Comment: @vivek_23 that is also a good suggestion. Kenneth you should have it so that you don't unnecessarily complicate other eloquent queries pertaining that model.

Comment: @us190190 You may edit your answer and add this part of migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast in query builder laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713490/cast-in-query-builder-laravel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use raw query to get the desired result.

```
$query = "CAST(framesize AS INTEGER) ASC";
DB::table('motor_size')->orderByRaw($query)->get();
```

However, a better approach should be to modify the column's data type. Doing this would:

1. Reduce the size of your table.
2. Optimize an index that includes that column.
3. Other eloquent queries will also require the above raw query, which is not suggested.

For doing this create a new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration AlterFrameSizeInMotorSizeTable
```

Add the following as up function definition:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('motor_size', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('framesize')->change();
    });
}
```

Then run the migration using:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to change the datatype of the column. I'm going to do that instead - seems like a better long-term solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```php
->orderByRaw('CONVERT(framesize, UNSIGNED) ASC');
```

OR

```php
->orderByRaw('CAST(framesize as UNSIGNED) ASC');
```